# Inequalities for sum of $k$ smallest degrees of a graph

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, computer-science

As part of a homework assignment, I am doing a proof for a generalised variant of [Karger's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karger%27s_algorithm) and am stuck at a particular step. I have proven that for a graph $G=(V,E)$ [writing $n=|V|$] with a [minimum $k$-cut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_k-cut) $C$,
$$|C| \leq \sum\limits_{l=1}^{k-1} d_l$$
where $d_1\leq d_2\leq\ldots$ are the degress of $v_1,v_2,\ldots\in V$. I need some way of estimating an upper bound on $\frac{|C|}{|E|}$ in terms of $n$ and $k$ alone. For instance in the case of minimum two-cuts (what are normally just called "minimum cuts") we can show
$$|C| \leq d_1 \leq \frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{l=1}^n d_l = \frac{2|E|}{n} \Rightarrow \frac{|C|}{|E|} \leq \frac{2}{n}$$

Any help would be appreciated (there is a strong possibility of an "[XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)"-situation here but please give it a go anyways).

Comment: You can get $2(k-2+\frac{1}{n})$ using the same idea. What type of bound do you need?

Comment: Ideally the bound of $\frac{|C|}{|E|}$ should be less than 1, as $1-\frac{|C|}{|E|}$ represents a lower bound on a probability.

Comment: @MathieuRundström I managed to prove that $\frac{|C|}{|E|} \leq \frac{2(k-1)}{n}$ using a similar approach with induction, but unfortunately for the reason stated above it is not very useful.

Comment: Any bound $>1$ will not be helpful anyways as we must have $|C|\leq|E|$ since the set of edges crossing $C$ is a subset of $E$.